# Iv only ever played original pokemon and want to play again

Tags: pokemon-series

Can I play soul silver and then play alpha sapphire? Then onto pearl and then black/white?

I have the first 3 games from a friend which is why I ask and I’d rather not go ds to Gameboy game, cheers :)

Comment: What's the question? There isn't really a story line in between games if that's what you're worried about.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to experience the story, you can play in any order you want.

Each Pokémon release (which comprises all editions released at the same time) have an independent story, with 2 exceptions:

- Generation 2 (GSC) and its remakes (HGSS) is a sequel to Generation 1 (RGBY) and its remakes (FRLG). While you don't need to have played Gen 1, you'll be missing some cool references, such as

  > the entire Kanto region and its league, as well as the battle against Red, your character from Gen 1.
- Generation 3 (RSE) and its remakes (ORAS) are the only release where each edition tells its own (slightly different) story. Ruby and Omega Ruby have you fight against Team Magma, whose goal is to reduce the sea level to have more land. Sapphire and Alpha Sapphire have you fight against Team Aqua, whose goal is to increase the sea level to have more water. Emerald lets you fight both simultaneously.

---

If your goal is to keep your Pokémon and carry them over to the next game, you'll need to play the games in order of generation, starting with Gen 3 (RSE and FRLG).

While there is no way to transfer Pokémon from Gen 2 to newer games, the Virtual Console versions of the Gen 1 games (RBY) can be transferred to Pokémon Bank and used in Gen 7 (SM & USUM) onwards.

Due to technical limitations, you can't transfer Pokémon from a newer generation game to an older one, with Gen 1 and Gen 2 being the only exception to the rule.

This means that you'll have to play in the following order instead:

1. (Gen 4) Soul Silver
2. (Gen 4) Pearl
3. (Gen 5) Black/White
4. (Gen 6) Alpha Sapphire

You can also play Pearl before Soul Silver if you wish, since they belong to the same generation.

Note that if you intend to experience all the story ***and*** keep your Pokémon along the way, you should consider playing Black 2 or White 2 (Gen 5) *before* moving on to Alpha Sapphire.

Comment: "Unfortunately, there is no way to transfer Pokémon from Gen 2 to newer games." If you're playing the Virtual Console versions, you actually can via Bank and Home, though they'll still have to skip gens 3-6 if you do.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery. I totally forgot about the VC releases...